# Vuetify v-select issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am trying to assign items to my v-select dropdown but i keep getting the message `no data available`, i have an array of objects. i am using the template slot but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have made a codepen for demonstration: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LKmZKZ?editors=1011

```
  <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-container>
     <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs4>
      <v-select :items="items" label="people">
        <template slot="selection-item" slot-scope="item">
          <v-icon :color="item.icon_color">{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
          {{item.name}}
          </template>
         </v-select>
      </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
   </v-container>
  </v-app>
 </div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
   return {
  items: [
    {name: 'Karen', icon : 'search', icon_color: 'red'},
    {name: 'Gordon', icon : 'person', icon_color: 'yellow'},
    {name: 'Craig', icon : 'opacity', icon_color: 'blue'},
    {name: 'Chris', icon : 'pets', icon_color: 'orange'},
     ]
   }
  }
 })
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: you have a typo : `v-select :ietms`

Comment: @SirDad i fixed it but now it just says [object object] in the dropdown.

Comment: @BernardPagoaga i fixed it but now it just says [object object] in the dropdown.

Comment: figured it out :  v-slot:item="{item, index}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-select` expects an array of strings as the value but you are binding an array filled with objects that's why you are seeing `[object object]`so you gotta add  `item-text` prop:

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
   name="item"
   label="Select a item"
   item-text="name"
></v-select>
```

Comment: v-slot:item="{item, index}" fixed it

Answer (score 0):

u are writing

```
<v-select :ietms="items" label="people">
```

should be

```
<v-select :items="items" label="people">
```

i never used vuetify but i found in [documentacion](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#prepend-append-item-slots) about this, then i forked your pen:
https://codepen.io/christiancazu/pen/mZLWpL

Comment: i fixed it but now it just says [object object] in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing item text item-text="name", thats why it says  [object object] in the dropdown

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-container>
     <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs4>
      <v-select :items="items" item-text="name" label="people">
        <template slot="selection-item" slot-scope="item">
          <v-icon :color="item.icon_color">{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
          {{item.name}}
          </template>
         </v-select>
      </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
   </v-container>
  </v-app>
 </div>
```

This should work